# How to show particular key value as first in Data tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Data tables to display the rows and columns. when I load the page particular key value should show first.

for example, I have the column as 'color' with values like red, green, blue, orange, white. Here I want to display 'Orange' as first when loading the page. is this possible?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [] ,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength" : 15,
        "bFilter": true 
          } );
} );
</script>
```

[This is my data here I want to list Orange Color as first always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpsj9.png)

Comment: give example of your data here

Comment: Apparently, there is no native option to implement that. But I suggest that you just modify the array that you use for rendering the data. In your server side loop, make that record appear first by rendering it first.

Comment: @NegiRox example data added.

Comment: you need to arrange your array according to your need

Comment: @JerdineSabio yes I tried that way too but my data is arrays of object so I'm not able to do this using array_unshift like those functions

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using - 1.9 or 1.10?